# Analytics show too many unassigned users

Tags: google-analytics

**Problem**
Google Analytics shows a large number of unassigned users.

**Context** 
We only collect data from inside the secured area of our web-application - thus no unassigned users should be counted. Most of the unassigned sessions originate from direct links in emails that go out to our users.

**App Details:**
- Angular 1.x
- SPA

**Tracking Code in HEAD:**

```
<script>
           (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
               function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
               e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
               e.src=’//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
               r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,‘script’,‘ga’));
           ga(‘set’, ‘anonymizeIp’, true);
           ga(‘create’,‘UA-XXX-1’, ‘auto’,
               {‘siteSpeedSampleRate’: 80}
           );
       </script>
```

**User ID call in top of BODY**

```
<script>
           setTimeout(function(){
               ga(‘set’, ‘userId’, document.getElementById(‘userId’).innerHTML);
           }, 8000);
       </script>
```

I appreciate any thoughts from you as we have tried many things and can't figure out whats wrong here...

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Lennart

Comment: Each set call must be followed by an interaction hit, or the value will not be transmitted to the Google Analytics servers. You do not show your "send" call in your code, but you might want to make sure that the userId is set before the pageviews.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So far, I haven’t figured out what to change. We’re using angulartics to submit the events etc. As we are in the Angular context, loading the user Id takes some time. That’s why we to the second call for the userId later, hoping that Analytics knows the session and can than add the userId, when available. As mentioned, this works around 50% of the time. Doesn’t seem to work for users directly opening our application when clicking on a link in an Email. Help with this is really appreciated.